# how to display a contacts list in accordion view?

Tags: javascript, client-side-rendering, contacts

I want to display a contacts list in SharePoint 2013 as accordion. I tried to use the code from https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-ccdb2a0e/view/Discussions/0?showDiscussionForm=True
and modified it a little bit.

But now my problem is to show the picture. For this i have the URL stored in the app. 
Has anybody a solution to show the picture and next to the picture the contact details.
Here's the code I used:

```
(function () {

    // jQuery library is required in this sample
    // Fallback to loading jQuery from a CDN path if the local is unavailable
    (window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"><\/script>'));

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render 
    var accordionContext = {};
    accordionContext.Templates = {};

    // Be careful when add the header for the template, because it's will break the default list view render
    accordionContext.Templates.Header = "<div class='accordion'>";
    accordionContext.Templates.Footer = "</div>";

    // Add OnPostRender event handler to add accordion click events and style
    accordionContext.OnPostRender = accordionOnPostRender;

    // This line of code tell TemplateManager that we want to change all HTML for item row render
    accordionContext.Templates.Item = accordionTemplate;

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(accordionContext);

})();

// This function provides the rendering logic
function accordionTemplate(ctx) {
    var title = ctx.CurrentItem["Project_x0020_Role"];
    //var Picture = ctx.CurrentItem["Picture"];
    var FullName = ctx.CurrentItem["FullName"];
    var WorkPhone = ctx.CurrentItem["WorkPhone"];
    var Email = ctx.CurrentItem["Email"];

    // Return whole item html
    return "<h2>" + title + "</h2><p>" +  "Name: " + FullName + "<br /> " + "Phone: " + WorkPhone + "<br /> " + "Email: " + Email+ "</p><br/>";

}

function accordionOnPostRender() {

    // Register event to collapse and uncollapse when click on accordion header
    $('.accordion h2').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    }).next().hide();

    $('.accordion h2').css('cursor', 'pointer');
}
```

Thanks in advance.

========================

This is how the table should look like:

[image: Table]

Comment: What value you have in `ctx.CurrentItem["Picture"]`?

Comment: Here's the Url to the mysite mThumb Picture stored.
`https://mysite.???.com/User Photos/Profile Pictures/mmayr_mThumb.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `function accordionTemplate(ctx)` as follows

```
return "<table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td><img src='" + Picture + "' /></td><td><h2>" + title + "</h2><p>" +  "Name: " + FullName + "<br /> " + "Phone: " + WorkPhone + "<br /> " + "Email: " + Email+ "</p></td></tr></table>";
```

**Update**

```
return "<h2>" + title + "</h2><p><table border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr><td><img src='" + Picture + "' /></td><td>" +  "Name: " + FullName + "<br /> " + "Phone: " + WorkPhone + "<br /> " + "Email: " + Email+ "</p></td></tr></table></p>";
```

Comment: looks good. the only thing is that i want to group the view by title and the picture should also be shown when the title was clicked (like name, phone etc.)

Comment: Try updated answer.

Comment: Sorry it's not working correctly. I posted a Picture how it should be working. Now the picture and the data are not "connected" so when I click on the header it opens nothing and the Picture with the data is shown always but this data should be "hidden" behind the title.